# Node.js Server says Request was cancelled, client says socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, multipartform-data, loopbackjs

Hello I am working on a REST API on Node.js platform on [Loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback). I am testing in Linux Mint 17 Quiana.

I am having trouble when it is related to Multipart/form-data requests. The  test is:

```
  it('Multipart request with two files, one right', function(done) {

var formData = {
  'dailyThemesId':'1',
  'themeId':'1',
  'pictureTimeZone':'GTM+1',
  'pictureText':'Pretty pics',
  file: {
    value:  fs.createReadStream('./test/File/fileSuperSmall.mp4'),
    options: {
      filename: 'video.mp4',
      contentType: 'video/mp4'
    }
  },
  video: {
    value:  fs.createReadStream('./test/File/fileSuperSmall.mp4'),
    options: {
      filename: 'video.mp4',
      contentType: 'video/mp4'
    }
  }
};
request2.post({url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000' +'/api/Pictures/upload' +'?access_token='+token1,
 formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

});

When this test is run I get the next log.

> upload failed: { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }

As far as I know it looks like server did stop the connection while the file was being uploaded.

At the server side a custom endpoint is created for the upload of files. This endpoint is expected to receive a multipart request. The parsing is done using [multiparty](https://github.com/expressjs/node-multiparty).

```
    Pictures.upload = function(req, callback) {
    var form = new Multiparty.Form({}), 
currentTime = new Date(),
clientId,
dailyThemesId, themeId, pictureTimeZone, pictureText, file;

if (req.accessToken) {
   clientId = req.accessToken.userId;
} else {
  return callback(new Error('Error: To upload a file you must be logged'));
}
if (!req.get('Content-Type').includes('multipart/form-data')) {
  return callback(new Error('Error: Message must be a Multipart'));
}

form.on('part', function(part) {
  part.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error at part parsing :', err, err.stack);
    // error handled at form level
  });

  if (part.name === 'file' && part.filename.endsWith('.mp4')) {
    file = part;
    console.log('file found');

  }
});
form.on('field', function (name, value){

  if (name === 'dailyThemesId') {
    dailyThemesId = value;
  } else if (name === 'themeId') {
    themeId = value;
  } else if (name === 'pictureTimeZone') {
    pictureTimeZone = value;
  } else if (name === 'pictureText') {
    pictureText = value;
  }
});
form.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error at form parsing :', err, err.stack);
});

form.on('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
  console.log('So far recieved bytes: ', bytesReceived);
  if (bytesReceived >= 1024000000) {
    console.log('Message is way too long');
    return callback(new Error('Http request in way to long'));
  }
});
form.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Closed multipart');
  if (dailyThemesId && themeId && pictureTimeZone && pictureText && file &&
    (process.env.NODE_SFTP_HOST === '127.0.0.0' || 
    process.env.NODE_SFTP_HOST === 'localhost')) {
      console.log('Sending local');
      sendFile (fs, file);

  } else if (dailyThemesId && themeId && pictureTimeZone && pictureText &&
     file ) {
          console.log('Sending ftp');
      startSftpConn(file);
  } else {
    console.log('Missing something');
    return callback(new Error('Missing data at the request'));
  }
});

form.parse(req);
```

Every time a file is uploaded I get the next error logged.

> Error at form parsing : [Error: Request aborted] Error: Request aborted
>       at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/home/francisco/NodeJs/dayN/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:183:17)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/francisco/NodeJs/dayN/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js:76:17)
>       at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.emitted [as emit] (/home/francisco/NodeJs/dayN/node_modules/emitter-listener/listener.js:122:21)
>       at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:284:11)
>       at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:297:5)
>       at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
>       at TCP._onclose (net.js:484:12)

At the end I am not sure why this is happening, ¿How come both report that the other end finished the connection? When there is no file involved it works perfectly. ¿May it be a loopback thing that does not allow long messages?
Any help is appreciated, that you so much.